# Reduce MySQL query amount with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, lag

I am building a "multiplayer world" with jQuery and PHP. Here is a bit how it works:

1. User's character's positions are taken from a database, user is plotted accordingly (the position values are CSS values - left and top)
2. User is able to move about using the arrow keys on the keyboard, making their character move using jQuery animations. While this is happening (on each arrow press) the user's position values are inserted into a database and updated.
3. In order to make this "global" (so users see each other) as you could say, the values need to be updated all at once for each user using AJAX

The problem I am having is I need to continuously call a JavaScript function I wrote which connects to the MySQL server and grabs values from a database table. And this function needs to be called constantly via `setInterval(thisFunction, 1000);` however my host just suspended me for overloading the server's resources and I think this was because of all my MySQL queries. And even after grabbing values from my database repeatedly, I had to insert values every few seconds as well so I can imagine that would cause a crash over time if enough clients were to login. How can I reduce the amount of queries I am using? Is there another way to do what I need to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the same thing as a chat system with regards to resource usage. Try a search and you'll find many different solution, including concepts like **long polling** and **memcached**. For example, check this thread: [Scaling a chat app - short polling vs. long polling (AJAX, PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313641/scaling-a-chat-app-short-polling-vs-long-polling-ajax-php)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into long polling - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology. This method allows you to establish a connection with your server, and then update it only when you need to. However by the sounds of it, you have a pretty intensive thing going on if you want to update every time, you may want to look into another way of storing this data, but if your wondering how big companies do it, they tend to have mass amounts of servers to handle it for them, but they will also use a technique similar to long polling.

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the positions in memory using `memcached` See http://php.net/manual/fr/book.memcached.php and save them all at once every few seconds into the database (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You could use web sockets to overcome this problem. Check out this [nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, it's to emulate or use actual sockets. Instead of constantly pulling the data (refreshing to check if there are new records), you can push the data over [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) which works in Chrome at the moment (at least to my knowledge, didn't try it in FF4) or you can use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for leaner long pooling. That way, the communication between players will be bi-directional without the need of MySQL for storing positions.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)

From their site:

Tornado is an open source version of the scalable, non-blocking web server and tools that power FriendFeed. The FriendFeed application is written using a web framework that looks a bit like web.py or Google's webapp, but with additional tools and optimizations to take advantage of the underlying non-blocking infrastructure.

The framework is distinct from most mainstream web server frameworks (and certainly most Python frameworks) because it is non-blocking and reasonably fast. Because it is non-blocking and uses epoll, it can handle thousands of simultaneous standing connections, which means it is ideal for real-time web services. We built the web server specifically to handle FriendFeed's real-time features — every active user of FriendFeed maintains an open connection to the FriendFeed servers. (For more information on scaling servers to support thousands of clients, see The C10K problem.)