# Node.js + Express: How to update page when something has been inserted into database?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I have messaging all set up, but when someone sends a message, I want the recipient to see the message without having to refresh the page.

It would also be cool that when a user receives a message, there is a notification/badge that appears to indicate a new message.

I'm a newbie only just delving into web development, so is this the scenario where I would use AJAX? I've been reading about it, and that seems to be the case. Is there a better way to do something like this with Node.js + Express?

I just need a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Server Send Events, or, Long polling, or, Timed Requests, or, Web Sockets...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the recipient see a message without refreshing a page can be achieved by AJAX.  Your situation where you want the user to receive a notification message is a common one.  There are several ways of achieving that.  You can do short-polling or long-polling, both of which can be achieved by AJAX [Scaling a chat app - short polling vs. long polling (AJAX, PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313641/scaling-a-chat-app-short-polling-vs-long-polling-ajax-php).  But if you're using Node, why not look into websockets.  Node and sockets literally go hand-in-hand.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

THere is a very good nodejs module for long pooling - http://socket.io/
So, you can send message from server when record is updated